# Why Rod is harder to hold at the edge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

A Rod has length of 50cm and radius of 5cm with sides names say A and B .

CASE 1
A bag is hanged in *MIDDLE* of the Rod name that C . Now a person holds that Rod with one hand from edge B . Now , the bag and Rod weighs 2Kg togather So , total force applied downwards would be almost 20N (20 newtons) which means the person has to apply only 20N force Upwards to hold that happens aswell the person applies 20N and is able to hold it in air easily.

*CASE 2*

- Now, the Rod and bag are same and the person is also same holding the Rod with a bag hanged on Rod from edge *B* BUT, the Bag is not in the middle of Rod the Bag is not on *C* it's position from Rod has been moved and its almost at the edge of rod *Almost at A*  so the bag has moved and is at opposite side from the person's hand . Now the observation has been made that person has to put SO much MORE effort to hold the ROD (with bag hanged) in Air   IN *CASE 2* Than *CASE 1*

So,  how much force is needed to hold that Rod in air in CASE 2
A) more than 20N force.
B) only 20N force
C) less than 20N force
D) non of the above
?
AND, why is it more difficult to Lift the Rod in CASE 2 compared to CASE 1 even though mass is same only the bag is moved from point C to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bag is connected to the rod and you don't care about whether things hang down, then the force would be the same. If the bag is only *resting* on the rod you would need to prevent the rod from turning. The actual numbers depend on how much of the rod can be held by the hand. The 'back' part of the hand needs to push the rod down to stop it turning, and the front part (finger) needs to balance this force plus the weight of the rod and bag, so it can take quite a lot of force from the different parts of the hand.

Comment: PETER- thanks for answering I really appreciate it :)

Comment: DANDAN0101 - thanks for answering dude

Answer (score 0):

The net force exerted to lift the rod in both cases is 20 N. But your observation is totally right - it is much harder to lift the rod if the weight is hanging further from your hand.

To explain this, we must consider the torque exerted by the mass. When you lift the rod, a simple model is that your hand contacts the rod in two places (you feel the rod press down against your hand on the side of your hand closer to the load; you feel the rod press up against your hand on the side of your hand further from the load). To stop the rod from rotating, you must exert a torque on the rod to cancel the torque exerted by the mass. This means that the force exerted by each side of your hand on the rod must increase, although the net force stays the same.